# Show and hide executing with jQuery toggle function with one click

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, toggle

I've been working on a blog in rails 4 with a jQuery quick reply to each post.

```
#new.js.erb:

  if ($('#<%= j "form_reply_#{@post.parent.id}"%>').length ) {
    $('#<%= j "form_reply_#{@post.parent.id}"%>').toggle();
  } else {
    $('#reply<%= j "#{@post.parent.id}"%>').after("<%= j render "form" %>");
  }

#link to new.js.erb in _post.html.erb:

<%= link_to "Reply", new_post_path(parent_id: post), id: "reply#{post.id}", remote: true %></p>
```

Around every other time turbolinks performs a partial page reload the show and hide both execute with one click on the "reply" link, causing the reply form to show and hide itself instantly. If I do a full page refresh everything will work fine. What could be causing this and how would I go about fixing it?